# Solr customizing with Websphere Commerce

Tags: solr, websphere, websphere-commerce

I have a strange requirement in Solr.

The business model is like for each store in state (say victoria), we have different sales catalog (like Richmond, Brunswick etc) which in turn act as fulfillment centers on their own.

so my url of storeId- vic and catalogId-Richmond will retrieve me catalogues with richmond's store.

Now the requirement is I need to filter out the products based on the inventory for each of these sales catalogues.

I constructed a TI table which has the following structure

catentry_id -------- QUANTITY_RICFUL-------------QUANTITY_BrunFUL
1234-------------------0------------------------------------20

I had incorporate the changes in solr query to add these columns in the final result too.

But I do not know how to filter out the products in the front end during catalogue navigation or during search.

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to ask here but it seems you are trying to display a `Quantity dropdown` or display an `Quantity field` under each product on a search page which to me makes no sense from a UI perspective. Also keep in mind if you have integrated with a 3rd party inventory model that runs every few mins/hours etc. **How often do you plan to run indexing etc?**

I would rather leave such complexity to a `Prodcut Detail` page. If you do require to show an `Quantity fiel`d on the search page I would rather prefer displaying a `QuickView popup/modal` that displays the color/size attributes with the `quantity dropdown` etc and enable a user to add an item to his/her shopping cart.

Comment: I do not understand your response. Are you asking me not to use this design to implement my solution? To answer your question, the indexing is run daily

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to tie the returned catalog entries in a list with inventory? For instance, when they click on a category you do not want to display products with no inventory?

This would be a customization you can either do at the Solr Level or at the JSP level. You should probably track inventory in commerce (import it) into a field Solr can key off of and then only return items with the flag set to greater than zero. I am not sure if you need actual inventory or just a boolean. Are you using a single fulfillment center or multiple ones? Multiple gets a bit trickier and it would require them to log in most likely but then fulfillment would be addressed by the ship to address.

If the store is set up with ATP inventory then you should just get this for free, as products not in stock will simply not be displayed. Check out this page in the infocenter - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.user.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fcosatpatpandnonatp.htm

Comment: Bob - I did all this. My problem is to refactor the results in the front end by passing the store id parameter to the solar query in the metadata parameter.